# Cannot read property 'removeClass' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I try to do tabs with jquery in joomla, using *Sourcerer* plugin, but it's not important.

My code perfectly works in jsfiddle and in local *.html* document, but not on live website.

It writes *

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeClass' of null

- in 7 string

Here is a code:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.tabs').on('click','a',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $hash = this.hash;
   $link = $(this);
   
      if ($link.parent('.active')){
   $('.tabs-block .active').removeClass('active');

   $('div.active').removeClass('active');
   $($hash).addClass('active');
   $link.parent().addClass('active');
      }
  })
 
})
```

```css
.tabs-block div{display:none;}
.tabs li{display:inline-block;}
ul.tabs{margin:0;position: relative;top: 2px;}
.tabs li {border:solid 2px #448ebe;border-bottom:none;border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;}
.tabs li.active{background-color:#fff;border-color:#66b366;opacity:1;}
.tabs-block div.active {display:block; border: solid #66b366 2px;border-radius: 5px;padding-left:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-block">
<ul class="tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#tab1"><img src="/images/other/fb.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2"><img src="/images/other/i.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="#tab3"><img src="/images/other/tw.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="#tab4"><img src="/images/other/vk_2.png"></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="active" id="tab1">
<p>Tab 1</p>
</div>
<div class="" id="tab2">
<p>Tab 2</p>
</div>
<div class="" id="tab3">
<p>Tab 3</p>
</div>
<div class="" id="tab4">
<p>Tab 4</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you including this js in the main html page? Is it in a a separate js file?

Comment: yes, in separate file, it looks like this <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/templates/jtrololo/js/tabs.js"></script>

Comment: but ion the included `html` file I am not seeing any reference of `tabs.js`

Comment: @user2181397 yes, sorry, it goes right after writtent html

Comment: Problem was in script order, i put jquery in template header and everything works now. Lol i wrote 3 different scripts to understand problem. Now i know js little more xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please double check your logic??

```
$('.tabs-block .active').removeClass('active');
$('div.active').removeClass('active');
```

In the first line you are removing class "active" which will get removed from below element as well.

```
<div class="active" id="tab1">
```

and elment will become this:

```
<div id="tab1">
```

Now, there is not div with active class and your second statement will not find any matching elements and you will get exception.

Comment: i fixed this and now have `$link.parent is not a function` D:

Comment: Solution in 1st post comments